# Getting the path between A and Xi within range R, so that it hits most targets inbetween

Tags: math, lua

I decided to draw an image for this:

[image]

There exist `i` X, where I know the x,y coordinates and radius from. My own position is `A` and I need to find the target `Xi`, so that the linear between me and the x,y coordinates of `Xi` goes through as many `X` as possible. In the picture above the solution was `X7` because there is no other linear going from `A` that hits more targets than 3.

It needs to be very efficient and is written in lua.

Comment: Soooo... what have You tried so far?

Comment: compute histogram of `atan2(xi.y-A.y,xi.x-A.x)` and use the most occurent one ...